# can i apply the jqgrid cell formatter retro-actively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jqgrid, grid

I'm implementing my own inline edit plugin within jqgrid, but the problem is after i save the value with ajax and put it back inside the tablecell, it loses the formatting it had originally.

is there a way to force the grid to re-apply formatting to that cell?

Comment: Everything is possible, but to answer on your question you should include the code which defines the grid. You should additionally write which column hes the described problem. Test data (one line of data) could be additionally required.

Comment: Is it using one of the built in formatters or a custom formatter?

Comment: custom formatter. i'm not just talking about one column, i want to be able to apply the formatter in any column to any cell at some point after the grid is complete

Comment: the code that defines the grid would not be helpful at this point, we are implementing a grid factory which only makes sense in the context of the application